# trouble updating items from mongo node driver where the CLI works well :)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoDB and trying to update items by ID.
Now, I think somehow the IDs are strings (created by using the raw nodeJS driver, not using mongoose or anything).

I can modify the item using the mongo CLI, but not from the nodeJS driver.

from JS (typescript actually hence the await)

```
    let result = await TrainingModel.updateById(data._id, updater);
    logger.debug("update:", data._id, updater, result);
```

gives me logger:

```
update: 5747430d63a8ccca38123556 { '$set': { trigger: 'ABC' } } { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }
```

From the mongo CLI:

```
  db.getCollection('TrainingModel').find(     {_id: "5747430d63a8ccca38123556" } )
{ "_id" : "5747430d63a8ccca38123556", "topic" : "dc*", "text" : "/image dc-kid", "trigger" : "bumx", "use" : "1", "keyword" : "kid", "isq" : "0" }

> db.getCollection('TrainingModel').update(     {_id: "5747430d63a8ccca38123556" },     { '$set': { trigger: 'XYZ' } }      )
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

> db.getCollection('TrainingModel').find(     {_id: "5747430d63a8ccca38123556" } )
{ "_id" : "5747430d63a8ccca38123556", "topic" : "dc*", "text" : "/image dc-kid", "trigger" : "XYZ", "use" : "1", "keyword" : "kid", "isq" : "0" }
>
```

So the update actually happens.

Any idea what might prevent the mongo driver from behaving differently than the CLI?

```
$ npm list | grep mongo
├─┬ mongodb@2.1.17
│ ├─┬ mongodb-core@1.3.17
├─┬ mongoose@4.4.17
│ ├─┬ mongodb@2.1.18
│ │ ├─┬ mongodb-core@1.3.18

$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
```

Comment: figured it out. our internal library was converting to an ObjectID, whereas the importer from JSON data was making the IDs into strings.

Answer (score 0):

_id is not a string in mongo anymore its the object type ObjectId which is in the mongodb driver, so instead of passing in just the string you need to pass

new ObjectId("stringid")

Note: make sure you bring in objectID

Import {MongoClient, ObjectId} from 'mongodb'

Make sure you use mongoclient.connect() to get a reference to your db then once you get the db in the call back use db.collection("collectionName", callback(err, col). Now inside the callback you have your collection on which case you can do col.findOneAndUpdate().

Just make sure the id your using is an ObjectId.

Comment: as you can see from the CLI output it's not: `"_id" : ObjectId("574764d332bec6f53b642d7a"),`.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to see in the cli i don't see you making it an ObjectId which is fine a string will work, as to the Why part i believe the cli driver will accept the string or objectid